# Adding a b2vec2 in a map with std::pair key and value

Tags: c++, box2d

I have a error when I'm trying to add element to my map, here is my simplified code :

I have a map :

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, b2Vec2> >, std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, b2Vec2> > > myMap; `  

b2Vec2 rVec (1, 1)  
std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, b2Vec2> > partA (std::make_pair ("test", std::make_pair(1, rVec ) ) );  
std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, b2Vec2> > partB (std::make_pair ("testb", std::make_pair(1, rVec ) ) );` 

myMap[partA] = partB; //When I add this line i get an error when compiling.`
```

I get the error : "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const b2Vec2' and 'const b2Vec2')."
If I replace every b2Vec2 type by a  int type in `myMap` definition and initialization, it works. So I think there is just an issue with b2Vec2 but I don't get it.

Comment: Looks like you missed some code in the examples snippets you've given. What's the definition of m_particleInteractTab for instance? You also start a line of code right after saying "I create two std::pair" that looks incomplete or superfluous . I'd like to help but I'd need to see more complete code or better formatted code or something like verifiable code.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I edited the code.

Comment: What is the `b2Vec2` type?  You're getting the error because there is no less than comparison operator for it (`operator<`).

Comment: Maybe a typedef or a using alias would help clarify the code. Like using intvec = std::pair<int, b2Vec2>; then replace those uses with this alias.

Comment: 1201 has it I believe. std::map does the less than comparison of the pair which I bet gets passed into its members leaving the b2Vec2 unsortable since there's no supported less than operator for it.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm If you enter your explanation as the answer then this question won't show up as unanswered anymore. Any reason not to do so?

Comment: @LouisLangholtz I've added an answer, but the question will still show up as unanswered unless it has an _accepted_ answer.

Answer (score 2):

The type used as a key in a `std::map` needs to have a less than comparison operator defined for it (`operator<`).  `std::pair` defines one of these, which requires that `operator<` be defined for the types in the pair.

In your case, you're getting the compile error because the `b2Vec2` type does not define `operator<`.